# Queue Jenkins job on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

The plugin for queuing jobs to Jenkins on VSTS is a very nice integration.

I know there is  REST API to queue a build in VSTS.

My question it is possible to queue a Jenkins build with parameters for the parameterized job using the VSTS REST API?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Jenkins Remote access API?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are separate softwares/systems, the [VSTS REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) are used for VSTS. The Jenkins has it’s own API that you can use it to start a Jenkins build, you can check this article: [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/remote+access+api).